# Zend url router setting

Tags: php, zend-framework, controller, router

How can I use Index Action in CommentController when url is  http://site.com/api/location/{location_id}/comment/

i have code

```
$r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('api/location/(.*)/comment',
            array('module' => 'api' ,'controller' => 'comment', 'action' => 'index'),
            array(1 => 'param1')
            );
    $router->addRoutes('route6', $r);
```

but it doesn't work, it does not do IndexAction but it returns OK. How can I fix it?

p/s: location is also a cotroller

Comment: remember that routes match in FILO order meaning that the last route added will be the first that a match is attempted on

Comment: thanks a lot, I just solve my problem with your suggest, he he

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$r = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('api/location/([\d]+)/comment',
    array('module' => 'api' ,'controller' => 'comment', 'action' => 'index'),
    array(1 => 'param1')
);
$router->addRoute('route6', $r);
```

Not that I changed the regex and changed addRoutes to addRoute

Comment: Thanks but it's wrong because it isn't the last $router i add.